# How can I run msiexec from cygwin to unpack a msi?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cygwin, windows-installer

I need to unpack (not execute, unpack) a msi in a cygwin makefile.

If I invoke from the windows command prompt the following

```
msiexec /a package.msi /qn TARGETDIR=C:\foo
```

The package is correctly deployed in C:\foo. However, if I try to perform the exact same operation from the cygwin prompt

```
msiexec /a package.msi /qn TARGETDIR=C:\\foobaz
```

All I get is the msiexec window stating the usage.
I can solve this problem in two ways, either running successfully msiexec as above, or by starting a windows command from the makefile, and have it invoke that operation.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to extract the msi from within cygwin to extract the msi....

Comment: @Ramhound: I do. The makefile has to unpack the msi somehow.

Comment: Does `TARGETDIR=/cygdrive/c/foo` give better results?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: nope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. I need to invoke

```
run msiexec /a package.msi /qn TARGETDIR=C:\\foobaz
```

in cygwin. I have no idea why, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

An msi can be unpacked with most zip utilities, like 7-Zip.
It will contain lots of things (like registry keys etc) that are irrelevant in a Linux environment, but you'll be able to get at any text, source or exe's.

Comment: Not by cygwin unzip, and I am not going to ask developers to install an additional utility and install it on all test machines.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone into the same problem, and right after I've seen this, I figured it out by myself that the slashes of the two options (or switches in terms of windows) "`/a`" and "`/qn`" should be double slashes "`//`":

```
msiexec //a package.msi //qn TARGETDIR=C:\\foobaz
```

That should work, at least on my machine it does.